# Slider Images not Showing

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

I have a new site - http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/ and the slider images are not showing... I thought it might be an issue with a .htaccesss file in the Media folder, but there isn't one there...

The image link when right clicked and open image in new tab is http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/timthumb.php?src=http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide3.JPG&w=980&h=390

so the image is actually http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide3.JPG which works fine, making me think its not an access/permissions issue, but perhaps a javascript problem?

How should I begin to diagnose this?

Thanks

Henry

Comment: Could you provide the code for your slider. The image links seem to be wrong.

Comment: looking at http://www.carbonyzed.co.uk/ my javascript functions are not presenet here, backgrounds, pageloads etc, so I think i'll start here, is there a script to test JS?

Comment: such as my jquery failing...

Comment: @HenryAspden **Please include the necessary info into the question instead of linking to your demo page.** Just include screenshots and code samples. As soon as you fixed your problem, the question will become useless for the community. Closed as "too localized". Please edit the question. After this is fixed, we can open it again.

Comment: found that I had a corrup JS file, not properly uploaded durin FTP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took at look at your site ( http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/ ) and found the following issues wrong:

```
1. Failed to load resource http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
2. Failed to load resource http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js
3. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/timthumb.p…http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide1.JPG&w=980&h=390
4. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/timthumb.p…http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide2.JPG&w=980&h=390
5. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/timthumb.p…http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide3.JPG&w=980&h=390
6. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/timthumb.p…http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide4.JPG&w=980&h=390
7. Uncaught ReferenceError: namespace is not defined crystelleclothing.co.uk/:104
```

What does this mean?
*You have a bunch of resources that aren't loading correctly. Starting with your Google Analytics and Facebook js files, to the 4 images within your sliders. You should check out how it is that your  tag is being prepared. If I look at it and cut out the fat to just this http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/media/images/default/slide1.JPG I get a legit image. I can tell you that just by looking at the html there's a syntax error.

Regarding where to start? Check out this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4436/1956 and look at my follow up answer. That will get you started on looking at your code.

*Slider: I listed the output from my JavaScipt Console in Chrome. The code is trying to use a variable 'namespace' before it is defined. You need to define that variable or give it a value prior to that section of code. It almost looks like you took that code from some type of template or example site? This is what a namespace is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace. It looks like the code is expecting you to change that to the namespace you want to use for your code.

Hope that helps!